# Can I remove ORDER BY from a Django ORM query?

Tags: django-orm

It seems like Django by default adds `ORDER BY` to queries. Can I clear it?

```python
from slowstagram.models import InstagramMedia
print InstagramMedia.objects.filter().query
```

```sql
SELECT
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`id`,
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`user_id`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`image_url`,
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`video_url`,  
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`created_time`,  
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`caption`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`filter`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`link`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`attribution_id`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`likes_count`, 
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`type`
FROM
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`
ORDER BY
  `slowstagram_instagrammedia`.`id`
ASC
```

```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use: [`clear_ordering`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ff723d894d9272ea721d1996432ffc806c2b8180/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1601) method from query

```
"""Removes any ordering settings. 

If 'force_empty' is True, there will be no ordering in the resulting
query (not even the model's default).
"""
```

Example:

```python
>>> from products.models import Product
>>> products = Product.objects.filter(shortdesc='falda').order_by('id')
>>> print products.query
SELECT "products_product"."id", "products_product"."shortdesc"
WHERE "products_product"."shortdesc" = falda
ORDER BY "products_product"."id" ASC
>>> products.query.clear_ordering()
>>> print products.query
SELECT "products_product"."id", "products_product"."shortdesc"
WHERE "products_product"."shortdesc" = falda
```

Comment: In Django 1.6 you have to use either `clear_ordering(True)` or `clear_ordering(False)`, indicating whether to force clearing of default model ordering.

Comment: 'RawQuery' object has no attribute 'clear_ordering'

Answer (score 54):

Actually, just do a `query.order_by()` is enough.

This is specified [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) although it is a bit hard to find. The docs say:

> If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call order_by() with no parameters.

Here is the implementation of `order_by`, for your reference -

```
def order_by(self, *field_names):
    """
    Returns a new QuerySet instance with the ordering changed.
    """
    assert self.query.can_filter(), \
        "Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken."
    obj = self._clone()
    obj.query.clear_ordering(force_empty=False)
    obj.query.add_ordering(*field_names)
    return obj
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `force_empty=False` is key here - it doesn't clear a model's default ordering.

Comment: The [`order_by` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) do say *If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call `order_by()` with no parameters.*

Comment: @aehlke – the call to add_ordering with no params _will_ clear a model's default ordering though, check the source.

Comment: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'order_by'

Comment: This worked for me to clear the ordering from another queryset.
   
`queryset2 = queryset1.order_by('folder')`
`queryset3 = queryset2.order_by()`

Answer (score -5):

Try to use `.order_by('?')` at the end of queryset.

Comment: This will order the queryset randomly, which is not the same as _not specifying an order method_, and add a performance penalty.

Comment: I don't know much which is default.