# How to disable sorting by primary key in Django Admin?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sorting

Django admin sorts by primary key **in addition to** sorting fields specified in the model "ordering" record, thus, making it necessary to have composite indexes on a model just to allow sorting, which can be very prohibitive on a moderate amount of data(~5 000 000 records)

This is a default behaviour of Django Admin selecting query

```
SELECT * FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.`added_at` ASC, `book`.`book_id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

I want to achieve the following behaviour

```
 SELECT * FROM `book` ORDER BY `book`.`added_at` ASC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: with the usual django nomenclature, book_id is *not* a primary key on that table. This is due to some other setting you have or which table headers you have clicked on in the admin

Comment: Well, I guess, Django takes as primary whatever is ```primary_key=True``` in models declaration. No, I have no other settings(or clicks) regarding sorting. If I remove ```ordering``` from admin class, it orders only by primary key.  If I try to order by anything, it orders by that field + primary key(that is the problem), because MySQL needs composite index to be able to order by two fields at the same time

Comment: you are still leaving everyone to guess in the dark. At least post your model and your admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128610/can-i-remove-order-by-from-a-django-orm-query

Answer (score 4):

I guess I'm a bit late in here, but this may help someone in the future.

Django enforces a `-pk` ordering in order to be sure resulting queryset is deterministic - see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L274) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L308-L314) for example.

If you really want to disable it you can create your own `ChangeList` subclass and override `get_ordering` method like:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class NoPkDescOrderedChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset):
        rv = super().get_ordering(request, queryset)
        rv = list(rv)
        rv.remove('-pk') if '-pk' in rv else None
        return tuple(rv)

class YourExistingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request):
        return NoPkDescOrderedChangeList
```