# How to avoid ordering by in django queryset, order_by() not working

Tags: python, django, optimization

I have a "big" db whith over 60M records, and I'm trying to paginate by 50.
I have another db whith ~8M records and it works perfectly, but with the 60M amount it just never loads and overflows the db.
I found that the problem was the order_by(id) made by django so I tried using a mysql view already ordered by id, but then django tries to order it again. To avoid this, I used order_by(), which is supposed to avoid any ordering, but it still does it.

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CropAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

        qs1 = qs.only('id', 'grain__id', 'scan__id', 'scan__acquisition__id',
                      'validated', 'area', 'crop_date', 'matched_label', 'grain__grain_number', 'filename').order_by()

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs1
```

The query made is still using order_by:

```
SELECT `crops_ordered`.`crop_id`,
       `crops_ordered`.`crop_date`,
       `crops_ordered`.`area`,
       `crops_ordered`.`matched_label`,
       `crops_ordered`.`validated`,
       `crops_ordered`.`scan_id`,
       `crops_ordered`.`grain_id`,
       `crops_ordered`.`filename`,
       `scans`.`scan_id`,
       `scans`.`acquisition_id`,
       `acquisitions`.`acquisition_id`,
       `grains`.`grain_id`,
       `grains`.`grain_number`
  FROM `crops_ordered`
 INNER JOIN `scans`
    ON (`crops_ordered`.`scan_id` = `scans`.`scan_id`)
 INNER JOIN `acquisitions`
    ON (`scans`.`acquisition_id` = `acquisitions`.`acquisition_id`)
 INNER JOIN `grains`
    ON (`crops_ordered`.`grain_id` = `grains`.`grain_id`)
 **ORDER BY `crops_ordered`.`crop_id` DESC**
 LIMIT 50
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Or a better way to work with a db of this size?

Comment: So the printed query is `str(qs1.query)`, printed before the if line? Just making sure there's nothing else interfering.

Comment: @Melvyn yes, that's correct!

Comment: I wonder if you are [using MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/222974/62282). Ordering by PK on sane databases should not result in table scans. You're doing everything right though, according to docs. Have you tried raising a bug with Django?

Comment: I'm using innodb as engine.

Actually you were on the right path, sorry for the misleading answer. I looked again at the str(qs1.query) with and without order_by():

1) with order_by() the query doesn't order the records
2) without order_by() the query orders them

But afterwards In case 1) when I look at the query using the django-debug-toolbar it adds the ordering, so it must be something else adding it.
I have removed the ordering_by id in the model, could it be the pagination?

Comment: The paginator only adds a warning about unordered querysets. In a default ModelAdmin, any ordering is applied in `get_queryset()`. `get_field_queryset()` is another candidate, but I assume that Crop is the main model, not the related, so it doesn't fit. I don't see how Django can do this, it must be in your code or apps. I would start with consumers of `get_queryset()` (Right click on method name -> Find Usages in PyCharm).

Comment: And on the Database front: I would run an EXPLAIN of both queries (with and without order by, both with LIMIT) and see what's up there. If crop_orders.crop_id is a pk, there should no significant time difference between the two. Unless we're hitting some index size limit and explain should show it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `order_by()` will work as there will most likely be a default parameter when Django implemented this function. Having said that, I believe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128610/can-i-remove-order-by-from-a-django-orm-query) has the answer that you want.

**Edit**

The link in that thread might provide too much information at once, although there aren't many details on this either. If you don't like Github, there's also an [official documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/query/) on this method but you'll have to manually look for `clear_ordering` by using `CTRL + f` or any equivalence.

Comment: Well I think that what's suggested in that post is what I already tried, from the docs:
** If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call order_by() with no parameters. **

Comment: Have you tried the article linked as "this thread"? It used `clear_ordering` and I'm unsure whether you tried it or not -- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128610/can-i-remove-order-by-from-a-django-orm-query) in case you can't find it.